# Why doesn't np.square return ouput as expected?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2 dimensional numpy matrix whose type is `numpy.ndarray` of `uint8`.
Now when I perform `np.square` on the array, it does not return the expected result.

Here's an example of the code on the console and its output after I create the numpy array:

`arr[0, 0]` outputs `203`

Now,
`np.square(203)` outputs `41209`

But,
`np.square(arr[0, 0])` outputs `249`

This odd behavior was also observed for the np.sqrt method.
[image]

Comment: I can't recreate this. `assert np.square(np.array([[10]], dtype=np.uint8)[0, 0]) == 100` is just fine

Comment: Can you post an all-inclusive functional example?

Comment: I have added the screenshot from the spyder console. Is there anything else that I should add to the question?

Comment: You are using `uint8` which has a range from 0 to 255. You are overflowing and therefore you get strange numbers.

Comment: That makes sense, I thought numpy would create a new array with the required data type and output the result into it. So basically I need to create a new numpy array with a data type that can fit these values, right?

Comment: Right.  Assuming that a particular language entity will "Do What I Mean" is often a mistake.  Read the documentation before depending on such an assumption.  Yes, I'm speaking from experience.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [numpy.org](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) `np.uint8`is `Unsigned integer (0 to 255)`

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[203, 32, 45, 34], [34,322,780,54]])
arr1 = arr.astype('uint8')
arr2 = arr.astype('uint16')

sq = np.square(203)
sq8 = np.square(arr1[0,0])
sq16 = np.square(arr2[0,0])

sq, sq8, sq16, type(sq), type(sq8), type(sq16)
```

output:

```
(41209, 249, 41209, numpy.intc, numpy.uint8, numpy.uint16)
```

`41209` is `249` in `uint8`:

```
num = np.array([41209])
num1 = arr.astype('uint8')
num1
>>> array([249], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: I shouldn't have assumed that numpy will handle this and output the result with required data type (uint16). Thanks for the code snippet, this makes it clear!

Comment: @malibu Why would you have expected it to output a different type than what you chose?

Answer (score 1):

`np.square` like other `ufunc` can return results with various dtypes.  Looks like it 'prefers' to return a matching dtype:

```
In [109]: np.square(np.array([203], 'uint8'),dtype=int)
Out[109]: array([41209])
In [110]: np.square(np.array([203], 'uint8'),dtype='uint8')
Out[110]: array([249], dtype=uint8)
In [111]: np.square(np.array([203], 'uint8'))
Out[111]: array([249], dtype=uint8)
In [112]: np.square(np.array([203], 'uint8'),dtype='uint8')
Out[112]: array([249], dtype=uint8)
In [113]: np.square(np.array([203], 'uint8'),dtype='uint16')
Out[113]: array([41209], dtype=uint16)
In [114]: np.square(np.array([203], 'uint8'),dtype='int')
Out[114]: array([41209])
In [115]: np.square(np.array([203], 'uint8'),dtype='float')
Out[115]: array([41209.])
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#casting-rules

and under `signature` parameter.

```
In [118]: np.square.types
Out[118]: 
['b->b',
 'B->B',      # uint8
 'h->h',
 'H->H',
 'i->i',
  ...]
```

There are more details in handling of casting and dtypes, but the basic point is that if using 'exotic' dtypes like `unit8` beware of overflow etc.  Even with 'int32' overflow can be problem, but at much larger numbers.  A more common problem arise when doing some calculation on integers that results in floats.

A recent SO about dtypes with `/=` operator.

[numpy.array's have bizarre behavior with /= operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855276/numpy-arrays-have-bizarre-behavior-with-operator)

Many times I've had to ask SO questions - what's the `shape`, what's the `dtype`.  Those are fundamental properties of a `numpy` array.  Getting those right is 80% of the debugging battle.