# numpy.array's have bizarre behavior with /= operator?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, division

I'm trying to normalize an array of numbers to the range (0, 1] so that I can use them as weights for a weighted random.choice(), so I entered this line:

```py
# weights is a nonzero numpy.array
weights /= weights.max()
```

However, Pycharm said there's an unfilled parameter to the `max()` function (`Parameter 'initial' unfilled`). I tried this in the REPL with the /= operator and with "regular" division (`a = a / b`) and got different results for both and a different error than Pycharm thought:

```py
>>> a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>> a.max()
3
>>> a /= a.max()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    a /= a.max()
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide
>>> a = a/a.max()
>>> a
array([0.33333333, 0.66666667, 1.        ])
```

I also realized that for a weighted random, the weights needed to *sum* to one rather than be normalized to it. But dividing it by the sum yielded the exact same `TypeError` using the /= operation (but Pycharm thought this was okay):

```py
>>> a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>> sum(a)
6
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a /= sum(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    a /= sum(a)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide
>>> a = a / sum(a)
>>> a
array([0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       ])
```

What have I come across here? Is this some bizarre bug in Numpy or does the /= operator have a different use or something? I know they use `__truediv__` and `__itruediv__` but I can't see why one has a problem and the other doesn't. I have confirmed this behavior with the latest version of Numpy from pip (1.19.2 on Windows x64).

Comment: What's the `a.dtype`?  What do you expect after the inplace division?

Comment: Try converting `a` to `np.float32`. In-place division is not defined on integers due to the possibility of requiring type conversion to a floating-point representation.

Comment: Either `float64` or `int32` (which will get converted to `float64` as a result of the operation I'm trying to do). Both array types exhibit this problem.

Comment: @G.Anderson AHA! Indeed using floats as the initialization values causes it to work properly. That's really interesting. It kind of suggests to me that what I found *could* be a bug, but it could also be intended behavior as suggested by @ Mateen Ulhaq.

Comment: accidentally deleted my previous comment. `np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])` works but `np.array([1,2,3])` throws the error

Comment: It's not a bug.  Even though the division produces a float, it cannot change the `a.dtype`.  The same is true for simple assignment:  try `a[0] = 10.23423`.  The value gets truncated to the integer dtype.

Answer (score 1):

It's because numpy cares the type. When you apply the division, you're changing `int` to `float`. But numpy won't let you do that! That's why your values should be already in `float`. Try this:

```
>>> a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
>>> a /= sum(a)
>>> a
array([0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       ])
```

But why did the other one work? It's because that's not an "in-place" operation. Hence a new memory location is being created. New variable, new type, hence numpy doesn't care here.

Comment: So it's still internally an int type even though a.dtype returns float64?

Comment: When you assign the same name to 2 different memory locations, the newer one gets the name and the old one no longer has a reference. That old one then falls under Garbage Collection. Read this [Object References and Garbage Collection](https://www.machinelearningwiki.com/python/python-variables-rules-conventions/) written by me. Try to read the entire blog to understand it properly.

Comment: I'm well familiar with Python's garbage collection and how variables work. I'm just slightly confused that numpy has this error with integer types, despite it claiming that the array's datatype is a float.

Comment: As I told you, it's because the type is changing. Try `a *= sum(a)`, it won't return any error. Because here the type is not changing.

Comment: @ntoskrnl4. If the string representation of an array has no decimal points after the numbers, the dtype is an integer type. `numpy.array([1,2,3])` creates an array with dtype `np.int_`. Not sure why you think `a` is a float...

Comment: @ntoskrnl4. When you do `a = a / sum(a)`, you create a new array, and since the result of `/` is a float, you get a float. You then reassign it to the name `a`. Your original array was of dtype `int` regardless. Use something like `np.asfarray(a)` to get a float array only if you pass in an int.